# Function for concatenating fields in Solr

Tags: function, solr, concatenation

Is there way to concatenate two fields values in Solr, e.g. to sort or group over these concatenated values like `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&sort=concat(field1, field2)`?

Update: the purpose for concatenating these fields is to allow grouping/collapsing over the concatenated field.

Answer (score 2):

for sorting, this would have the same result: `&sort=field1 asc, field2 asc`

Comment: That is not true if d1={field1=ab, field2=d} and d2={field1=a, field2=d} then d1 < d2 if you sort on concat(field1, field2) but d1 > d2 if you sort on field1 and then on field2.

Comment: Unfortunately it is grouping that has major importance for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wish there would be such a function. There is already jira for that: [SOLR-3702 :: String concatenation function](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3702). But not resolved yet.. Feel free to upvote :)